# Cannot preview Octopress generated website

Tags: ruby, localhost, octopress

I am new to Jekyll and I am trying to build a blog using static pages with Octopress.

`rake` is generating the site correctly without any errors but when I try to preview the site, depsite that the server starts without any error

```
>>> Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
[2014-02-23 15:23:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-02-23 15:23:50] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32]
[2014-02-23 15:23:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1996 port=4000
```

It will throw errors when I try to access `localhost:4000` from my web browser and will not serve the files

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2014 15:25:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0500
[2014-02-23 15:25:25] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
        c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
        c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
        c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

I am running Windows 8.1 and I have been trying `rake preview` with both Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0 and also both x86 and x64 architectures on different machines. Also I tried to disable my firewall but it did not fix the issue.

I'd really appreciate some help to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe the windows firewall has not allowed the connection.

Comment: I use my antivirus firewall (NOD32) and I already tried to disable it but no change.

Comment: It is not that you disable the firewall, do not do this, there is a reason for the firewall. It is that you check if the firewall has blocked your webbrick/ruby or the port. Specifically the firewall already build in Windows. Because sometimes it blocks access to server scripts silently. Somewhere you can inspect the blocked connections of the firewall, but I have a different windows version, so you need to find out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, it looks like this may be a WEBrick specific error with Windows and IE (you didn't list the browser(s) you tried, but most results also list IE as a culprit).  I would try:

1. Hitting `http://localhost:4000` from Firefox/Chrome and see if the error persists
2. Changing your default web server from WEBrick to something else (I'd recommend the [Ruby Thin Server](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)). An easy walkthrough specifically for Octopress and the Thin server can be found at [this blog post](http://blog.geoffpetrie.com/blog/2012/10/14/octopress-change-the-default-preview-server/).

Comment: I am using exclusively Chrome. I will have a try to an alternative web server. Thanks.

Comment: Thin works like a charm! Thank you very much. Too bad I could not find a solution but this is a really good workaround. I had to move to 32bits version of Ruby to get Thin to work though.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. I know it didn't solve your original problem, but a workaround is definitely better than not working.

Answer (score 0):

From Octopress [documentation](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/), it is recommended that you use Ruby 1.9.3. You can easily get Ruby 1.9.3 and other useful tools for Windows system by installing [railsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en).

Comment: I did try Ruby 1.9.3 with RailsInstaller but I still have the same issue.